# Check if $f$ has a strict minimum at $c$ and is not monotone on both sides

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I made an example of ***infinitely differentiable*** function $f(x)$ at $c$ which has a strict local minimum at $c$ and is not increasing on any interval $[c, c + \delta]$ and is not decreasing on any interval $[c - \delta, c]$ .

Mees de Vries and Arin Chaudhuri helped me to make the example.

But I am not sure that my example is correct, so please check the correctness of my example.

$f(x)$ is defined as follows:

$$f(x) :=\begin{cases} g(x) & \text{ when }x > 0 ,\\ 0 &\text{ when }x = 0,\\  g(-x) &\text{ when }x < 0,\end{cases}$$

where $g(x) := \frac{4}{5} \sqrt{2} \exp(-\frac{1}{x}) + \exp(-\frac{1}{x}) \sin(\frac{1}{x})$.

Comment: Have you tried graphing it?

Comment: Yes and the graph was good.

Comment: What problem did you encounter when you try to check that?

Comment: infinitely differentiablity of $f(x)$ at 0 ,etc.

Comment: looks not bad to me. Why do you have such complicate factor in front of $g(x)$? How have you shown that $g$ or $f$ are smooth?

Comment: Mees de Vries and Arin Chaudhuri showed that $\exp(-\frac{1}{x}) \sin(\frac{1}{x})$ is smooth.

Comment: for smoothness of $f$ at $x=0$ you only need to check $f^{(n)}(0^-) = f^{(n)}(0^+)$ for every $n$ ... obviously it should be zero ... otherwise your example is wrong :)